# Javascript checking if array includes returns true/false depending on position

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code that takes users input and runs a command on the server.

i have blacklisted some letters and words that wont be run in an array called refuse

I use this to check if the user submitted command contains any of the blacklisted commands

```
var result = refuse.filter(e => args.indexOf(e) !== -1).length === args.length
console.log(result)
```

For example localhost is blacklisted if a usersubmitted command starts with localhost it returns true.

but if it contains and DOSENT start with the blacklisted command it returns false.
if the user submitted command is `123 localhost` it gets stored in an array like this

```
[ '123', 'localhost' ]
```

Comment: What is your question  ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution finally at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-if-two-arrays-contain-any-common-item-in-javascript/

```
function findCommonElement(args, refuse) {
from command

    // Loop for array1
    for(let i = 0; i < refuse.length; i++) {

        // Loop for array2
        for(let j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {

            // Compare the element of each and
            // every element from both of the
            // arrays
            if(refuse[i] === args[j]) {

                // Return if common element found
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return if no common element exist
    return false;
}
  findCommonElement()
```